# How to manage 'order' columns in database table with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I didn't find much information about database locks for Laravel and documentation is extremely vague.
So, imagine I have this table:

```
 item
+–––––––––––––––––––––--+
|id         int(10)     |
|name       varchar(255)|
|parent_id  int(10) [FK]|
|order      int(10)     |
+–––––––––––––––––––––--+
```

I want to lock it (can be the whole table, but would be better if it were only the selected rows, usually the ones that have the same parent_id), then update the order column on those rows, considering that several people are updating at the same time.

I understand that the user who saves it last will overwrite the order and that's ok in this case, the only thing I can't let happen is the following:

```
User A, B
A saves item[1] with order = 1
A saves item[2] with order = 2
B saves item[1] with order = 2
B saves item[2] with order = 3
B saves item[3] with order = 1
A saves item[3] with order = 3

End result:
item[1]->order = 2
item[2]->order = 3
item[3]->order = 3
```

There's inconsistency right there.
I plan on creating a UNIQUE index on columns `(parent_id, order)`, which prevents inconsistency, but I still need the locks to provide responsiveness for the user (just making the update fail is not a solution).

Maybe with the UNIQUE index plus a transaction will solve it?
Something like:

```
DB::transaction(function() use($item, $newOrderArrayOrSomething) {
    // $item->order updates
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked this one http://laravel.com/docs/queries#pessimistic-locking ?

Comment: Yeah, but the full "documentation" available for the matter has literally two redundant sentences:
`To run the SELECT statement with a "shared lock", you may use the sharedLock method on a query.` and `To "lock for update" on a SELECT statement, you may use the lockForUpdate method on a query.`
I have no idea of what they both do or if I can use them with Eloquent and how am I supposed to do the update (because the only example shown for each one is for a select).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DB::transaction(function() use($item, $newOrderArrayOrSomething)
         {
            $item= Item::find($item);
            $item->order= $newOrderArrayOrSomething;
            $item->save();
         });
```

Comment: That's what I wrote in the question, but I don't think a transaction solves the concurrency problem, it only helps when something fails inside of the transaction so all changes will rollback.
For it to work, I need a way to lock the selected rows open a transaction to update one by one and save and then unlock the rows.